# Как реализовать обновление баз данных на ежедневной основе?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, база-данных, парсер

Мне необходимо создать сайт на подобие https://koronavirus-today.ru/

Пытаюсь сейчас создать парсер, срабатывающий каждый раз при заходе на сайт.
После чего сохранять данные в mysql и в дальнейшем уже брать их оттуда.

**Вот примерно так выглядит база данных:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот так должен выглядеть график, выводимый на основе этих данных:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а теперь к сути. Как можно такое сделать?
Какой алгоритм использовать? Мне нужно чтобы при каждом заходе на сайт обновлялись данные за текущий день, а на следующий день последние сводки можно было бы вытащить из базы данных.

**P.S.** *Возможно, я сложно расписал всё тут. Если это так - спрашивайте, я расскажу поподробнее.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить, есть ли данные в базе.
Если нет - добавить.
Если есть - взять из базы.